# How do I enable single click for Dolphin in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, kde, filemanager, dolphin

I installed the Dolphin File Manager in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt-get install dolphin
```

I can't find any settings to enable "single click to open files or folders". How do I enable this feature in Dolphin whilst using Ubuntu 20.04 and GNOME?

These various methods for KDE users don't seem to work in Ubuntu [[1]](https://superuser.com/questions/1426077/how-to-enable-and-disable-double-click-mouse-options-in-kde), [[2]](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=156480), [[3]](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/how-to-disable-single-click-to-open-files-programs-in-kubuntu-4175673910/).

Comment: The methods still work; but a quick glance of the links you provided all refer to making changes in Qt5/KDE settings; ie. packages you've not installed. The only changes GNOME makes with regards Qt5/KDE relate to the theming so when Qt5/KDE/KF5 apps are used; they look okay. To make changes to the base Qt5/KDE system you'll need more configuration apps I believe.  You can operate everything within Dolphin.Configure though without additional packages.